# TYPO3 TypoScript: Display a list of subpages with content on parent page

Tags: typo3, archive, typoscript

I am trying to create an archive page that displays a list of subpages, similar to WordPress but display the parent's subpages instead of posts. I want the archive page to include the following from the subpage:

- Title
- First image
- First 150 words of regular text element

At the moment I can display a page title, but that's where I got stuck. I am placing the code in a sub template. Here is the code.

```
lib.portfoliolist = CONTENT
lib.portfoliolist.table = pages
lib.portfoliolist.select {
    pidInList = this
}
lib.portfoliolist.renderObj = COA
lib.portfoliolist.renderObj {
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="project">|</div><hr />
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        field = title        
        wrap = <h2>|</h2>
        10.typolink.parameter.field = uid
    }
}
```

If it helps, all of the images are within the fileadmin/user_upload/ directory, and this is my page structure:

- Root

  - Home
  - About
  - Project Portfolio

    - Project 1
    - Project 2
  - Blog
  - Contact Us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out myself, all I had to do was call for content in a separate query. For those that are looking to achieve something similar, here is the code I used to help you out.

```
lib.portfoliolist = CONTENT
lib.portfoliolist.table = pages
lib.portfoliolist.select {
    orderBy = sorting ASC
}
lib.portfoliolist.renderObj = COA
lib.portfoliolist.renderObj {
    stdWrap.allWrap = <div class="row">|</div>
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="project col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">|</div>
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        field = title   
        wrap = <h2>|</h2>
        typolink.parameter.field = pages.uid
    }
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            pidInList.field = uid
            selectFields = header, bodytext
            orderBy = sorting ASC
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            30 = TEXT
            30.value {
                field = bodytext
                wrap = <div>|</div>
            }
        }
    }   
}
```